# Customising Page Numbering - Graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, numbering, page-numbering, tikz-styles

I'm trying to customise bottom page numbering with some images (apologies if this question has been already asked). I have tried TikZ package, but still cannot encircle page number. MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\rlap{ \ifodd\value{page}\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{scope}
    \draw[thick] (1,1) circle(0.3cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}\else$\circ$\fi}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

But I would like to have the following:

[image]

Any approach that achieves this would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What should happen to larger page numbers, e.g. page 10? Currently you seem to want to differentiate between odd and even pages. Please clarify what should happen on even pages.

Comment: Does it work?
```\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{{ \ifodd\value{page}\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
\begin{scope}
\node[draw,circle] (1,1) {\arabic{page}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}\else$\circ$\fi}}
\begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}```

Comment: @JairoADelRio many thanks! It does work! Is it also possible to include half/quarter circle (instead of full) using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `circledsteps`  package (which relies on tikz) to do that:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\Circled[inner xsep=6pt, inner ysep=6pt]{\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]